# Should I use minor version in my docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, version

Sometimes, I only see major version in docker-compose.yml file like `version: '3'`. 
Other times, I can also see the minor version like `version: '3.7'`

I didn't find any best pratice for this.

Is it better to specify just the major version and be more flexible or fix the format to the minor version and be more strict ?

Comment: I always use the major only, unless I need a specific feature that exists in one of the minors. Sort of following the "optimistic versioning" approach - don't be too specific unless you have a reason.

Comment: I liked your idea but I just find that the major version 3  was in fact associated to the minor version 3.0. You can see this with the command `docker-compose config`. I found this response [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1330759/what-is-the-actual-compose-version-of-a-file-if-i-do-not-specify-a-minor-version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always specify the minor version, else `<major>.0` is used!

From the [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#v2-and-v3-declaration):

> **v2 and v3 Declaration**
>
> Note: When specifying the Compose file version to use, make sure to specify both the major and minor numbers. If no minor version is given, 0 is used by default and not the latest minor version.